# Parse Wikipedia lists and descriptions using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Not being terribly familiar with regular expressions, I need to find a way to parse lists of items from Wikipedia. I've pulled the content using Wikipedia's api.php and I am left with data that looks like this:

```
    ==Formal fallacies==
    A [[formal fallacy]] is an error in logic that...

    * [[Appeal to probability]] –  takes something for granted because...
    * [[Argument from fallacy]] –  assumes that if an argument ...
    * [[Base rate fallacy]] –  making a probability judgement...
    * [[Conjunction fallacy]] –  assumption that an outcome simultaneously...
    * [[Masked man fallacy]] –  ...

    ===Propositional fallacies===

    * [[Affirming a disjunct]] –  concluded that ...
    * [[Affirming the consequent]] –  the [[antecedent...
    * [[Denying the antecedent]] –  the [[consequent]] in...
```

So, I need a way to pull the data so that:

- We are only paying attention to lines starting with * [[
- Anything between * [[ ]] is the name
- The remaining content after the - is the description

Comment: `[[]]` is *not* the title. It just marks up links.

Comment: For what I need the data for, I need the info separated in two parts (Fallacy Name) / (Fallacy Description). Perhaps calling it name would be better than title

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: My previous code was similar to Casimir's post. I didn't include it since I figured I was far off and was recieving empty data as my result

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this do the job:

```
preg_match_all('~^\h*+\*\h*\[\[(?<name>[a-z ]++)]]\h*+[-–]\h*+(?<description>.++)$~imu', $text, $results, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($results as &$result) { 
    foreach($result as $key=>$value) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) unset($result[$key]); }
}
echo '<pre>' . print_r($results, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: This is almost what I had before but it's returning an empty array. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's strange, It works for me, I tested it. Perhaps a spaces issue somewhere.

Comment: Perfect, you rock. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First replace

```
^((?!\*\s\[\[).)*$
```

with blank. This will delete lines that don't contain * [[

Delete newlines replace

```
^\n|\r$
```

with blank.

Here is regex to get the title and description:

```
^\s+\*\s\[\[([^\]\]]*)\]\]\s–(.*)
Title: "$1", Description: "$2"
```